# Installer built with Install4j - Arrow keys cannot be used to navigate across buttons during install

Tags: install4j

We have an enterprise product with installer built using install4j. The issue we have is that the Arrow keys cannot be used to move across buttons on the install screens ("Next", "Back", "Cancel" etc.)
It is a general standard (I looked at few software installers - PostgreSQL, GIT Shell etc) and these do support moving across the buttons using arrow keys.

The install4j version we are using is 5.1.11. Does it have such a support ? If yes, how, if No, is there a chance that we might have this facility in some future versions ?

Answer (score 0):

Use <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> and <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd> to navigate between screens. Left and right would not work as keyboard shortcuts, for example when a text field is focused.