# How to enable Keyboard Accelerator in install4j

Tags: install4j

Is there as way to enable keyboard accelerator in install4j (specifically v6 and up)?

I know of [moving between screens using keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34917446/installer-built-with-install4j-arrow-keys-cannot-be-used-to-navigate-across-bu), but this is not the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All form components with a leading label can have keyboard shortcuts. They are defined in the "Text" property of the leading label.

To configure a keyboard shortcut, prefix the mnemonic character in that property with `&`, e.g.`&User`. The prefixed character will be underlined and the platform-specific keyboard shortcut (e.g. <kbd>ALT+[character]</kbd> on Windows) will allow the user to quickly navigate to the associated component with the keyboard.